# How to assign dataset values in RDLC report header?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005, rdlc

I am using RDLC report with Microsoft visual studio 2005. In my report header, I have a textbox called textbox1 which is referring to a value of another textbox placed in the report body in this way:

="Agency Name: " & ReportItems!textbox2.Value

My textbox1 is displaying the agency name correctly for my first page, however it did not appear in the subsequent pages.

Expected Result: All the pages are displaying "Agency Name: Testing123"

Actual Result  : Only the first page is displaying "Agency Name: Testing123", the subsequent pages display only "Agency Name: "

My problem is similar to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/965589f8-d3cc-4eca-8519-c21f9b006f4d/how-to-assign-dataset-values-in-header-in-rdlc-report

However, I'm not able to resolve my issue using the solutions provided in it.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is ReportItems!textbox2 getting it's value from? If it's a dataset value try using this directly instead of referencing an item in the report body.

Comment: The problem is report header weren't allowed to use dataset values. Thanks buddy but I've figured another method to populate my header values by using report parameter.

Answer (score 2):

1.Take Textbox from Toolbox into report.rdlc.

2.Right click on Textbox and select Expression option.

3.=First(Fields!ColumnName.Value, "Datasetname")

4.ok

Comment: This returns 1st row value of datasets, what is the function to get the second row?